# In PowerShell script, how can I restore packages to resolve error: This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer

Tags: powershell, msbuild, nuget

I am tasked with writing a PowerShell script to download the latest source code for a given branch, rebuild it and deploy it. The script I've written, is able to download projects, and in most cases has been able to rebuild them. But with one web project I get this error:

```
error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.0.1\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.
```

I've researched if PowerShell has a Update-Package command like the one available in the VS command prompt but have been unable to find the equivalent.

I know there's a cmdlet for Packages but from what I've seen they're used to update a specific package...what I need is to be able to have it download/update all packages referenced in the project.

Some points that might be of interest...

When I get latest on the solution to a new empty folder, the only thing in the packages folder is Modernizr.2.6.2. This is the same whether I'm getting latest in VS or in my PowerShell script.

If I open the solution within VS 2017, I am able to rebuild the solution with no problems. It downloads/installs over a dozen other packages...one of which is the Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props package referred to in the error message.

But if I delete everything and re-download the source code and then through my PowerShell script I call MSBuild to rebuild the solution I get the error mentioned above.  It never seems to download/install the missing packages.

Anyone have any ideas how I can use MSBuild within my PowerShell script to rebuild the project and have it automatically update/install any packages it needs?

Thanks

Comment: Seems the project has specified an old version of the .NET compiler instead of the system installed one. Can you not update the project to use a newer one?
If not then see if there's a repo that can provide it, add it as a repository to PS then use the PS command: Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -RequiredVersion 2.0.1 -Source RepoName ?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a solution to my problem on this page :[Quickly Restore NuGet Packages With PowerShell](http://www.dogsncode.com/2015/03/31/quickly-restore-nuget-packages-with-powershell/)

On that page is a script that uses Nuget.exe to download the packages based on the packages.config:

```
#This will be the root folder of all your solutions - we will search all children of 
this folder
$SOLUTIONROOT = "C:\Projects\"
#This is where your NuGet.exe is located
$NUGETLOCATION = "C:\Projects\NuGet\NuGet.exe"

Function RestoreAllPackages ($BaseDirectory)
    {
        Write-Host "Starting Package Restore - This may take a few minutes ..."
        $PACKAGECONFIGS = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $BaseDirectory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -eq     "packages.config")}
        ForEach($PACKAGECONFIG in $PACKAGECONFIGS)
            {
                Write-Host $PACKAGECONFIG.FullName
                $NugetRestore = $NUGETLOCATION + " install " + " '" + $PACKAGECONFIG.FullName + "' -OutputDirectory '" +     $PACKAGECONFIG.Directory.parent.FullName + "\packages'"
                Write-Host $NugetRestore
                Invoke-Expression $NugetRestore
            }
    }

RestoreAllPackages $SOLUTIONROOT
Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

I modified and added this function to my PS script and call it first to download all the packages and that does the job!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `restore` target of MSBuild to download NuGet packages. You can do that by running something like:

```bsh
git clone [your repo]
cd [your repo]
msbuild /target:Restore [Your Solution]
msbuild [Your Solution]
```

Comment: I tried that as well but it appears that it only works if the packages info is stored in your csproj file rather than in the packages.config.  In my case the packages info is stored in the packages.config so the only way I was able to make it work was using the PS script I posted above.

Comment: Yes that may be the case. If you have the bandwidth to do so, I recommend you upgrade your projects to use the new [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) format, it simplifies many common NuGet use cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildVS
{
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $path,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [bool] $nuget = $true,
        
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [bool] $clean = $true
    )
    process
    {
        $msBuildExe = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
        if ($nuget) {
            Write-Host "Restoring NuGet packages" -foregroundcolor green
            & "$($msBuildExe)" "$($path)"  /p:Configuration=Release /p:platform=x64 /t:restore
        }

        if ($clean) {
            Write-Host "Cleaning $($path)" -foregroundcolor green
            & "$($msBuildExe)" "$($path)" /t:Clean /m
        }

        Write-Host "Building $($path)" -foregroundcolor green
        & "$($msBuildExe)" "$($path)" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:platform=x64

        
    }
}
```